# Cannot Retrieve Collaborators for Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-sites, google-api-python-client

I'm finding that I'm unable to retrieve the Owners, Editors and Viewers for Google Sites within a particular Google Apps domain.  The functions simply returns empty in both Apps Script (getOwners, getEditors, getViewers) and Python / Sites Data API when accessing the ACL Feed for a SiteEntry.  (Via the API, all I can see are the domain-level permissions.  No user permissions are visible.)

It only behaves this way in a particular Google Apps for Business domain.  The functions return the correct results in my development Google Apps domain, i.e. working as I would expect it to.  So, it would seem to be a Google Apps domain configurable or some other wide-reaching configuration.  I've heard that G+ privacy settings can impact the ability to access email addresses in Drive permissions, but I don't believe that's the case here.  The domain that exhibits this issue only has 3% of users with the G+ service enabled.

Having difficulty isolating this further.  Has anyone experienced this before / know the resolution or a workaround?  Thanks for your time.